# gitlab protected branches option not finding in project edit settings

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to make master branch to restrict. I mean no developer should be able to push into it directly, instead code should get pushed into it only after 'merge request' accepted.

So after searching in google, I found that we can do using 'protected branches' option. But unfortunately, after I logged into gitlab, I am not finding 'protected branches' option at all.

**For eg:** In project edit settings ie., http://gitlaburl/xyz/proj/edit , I am able to see options like members, deploy keys, web hooks, services but not 'protected branches' option.

Currently all added gitlab members are set to 'owner'

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches

example url: 
https://gitlab.com/YOUR-USER/YOUR-PROJECT/-/settings/repository#js-protected-branches-settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your repo (myRepo) and the breadcrumb path is:
myRepo => settings => repository => settings => 'protected branches' will appear in the Right Panel.
Points:
For me it was very difficult to find, because I kept looking at the left panel! Also for some reason, the 'repository' settings, inside the settings of the repo was confusing.

Answer (score -1):

**Update for GitLab (version 12):**

Go to the project, then settings, Repository and there you can find "protected branches" in the menu on the right (i.e., http://gitlaburl/xyz/proj/-/settings/repository).

---

**For older GitLab (as of 2015):**

Go to the project, then settings and there you can find "protected branches" in the menu (i.e., http://gitlaburl/xyz/proj/protected_branches).

You did not say which version of GitLab you are using. Maybe you're using a very old version there this option was "hidden" on the branch overview page.

---

Btw. owners can push to protected branches, see permissions: https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions.md